# Is this a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\{(a+b,a-b,|a|):a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}.$

Is this a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$? I am not able to start.

Comment: Look at the third coordinate. Now multiply with a negative scalar. If instead of $|a|$ you have just $a$, would this be a subspace? (Just try out the closure under addition and scalar-multiplication)

Comment: Start by checking if (0,0,0) is in the set. Then find some simple example vectors in the set and multiply them by positive and negative scalars.  That's always a good way to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition, you have to check it is closed under addition and scalar product.However here is a counterexample:

Let $a=1,b=0,$ and get $(1,1,1)\in V.$ Let $a=-1,b=0,$ and get $(-1,-1,1)\in V.$ Now $(1,1,1)+(-1,-1,1) = (0,0,2)$ is not in $V$ for if so then solve $a+b=a-b=0$ we get $a=b=0$ and $|a|=0\neq 2.$

The idea of the counterexample is by: let $(a_1+b_1,a_1-b_1,|a_1|),(a_2+b_2,a_2-b_2,|a_2|)\in V,$ then if it's a subspace we will have $((a_1+a_2)+(b_1+b_2),(a_1+a_2)-(b_1+b_2),|a_1|+|a_2|)\in V,$ and observe the problem of picking new $a,b$ making it in $V.$

Answer (score 2):

A very useful exercise for you: prove the following.

> Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a subspace, and let $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ (where $k \leq n$) be the set given by projecting $A$ onto some selection of coordinates. Then $B$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Now project your space onto the third coordinate. Do you have a subspace?

Answer (score 1):

No, the absolute in the third coordinate is problematic. This means that the third coordinate is never negative, but it can be positive as $a$ can be non-zero. This makes the set not closed under scaling.

For example setting $a=1$ and $b=0$ you get the element $u=(1,1,1)$, but if it were a subspace you would have $c\cdot u$ be a member for all $c$, in special $-1\cdot(1,1,1) = (-1,-1,-1)$ would be, but the third component would need to be non-negative.